# Does mongoose store all objects returned from query in memory?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I query using mongoose and the result set coming back is 1 million records, are all those records stored in memory?

Can I iterate the results such that a cursor is used?  Is this done automagically?  If so is there a certain way I need to iterate the results?

```
Reports.find({}, function(err, reports) {
  // Are all million reports stored in memory?

  reports.forEach(function(report) {
     // iterate through reports
  });

  // another way to iterate
  for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
    var report = reports[i];
  }
});
```

Comment: And where would they be stored if not in memory? You clould make several queies using `limit` at least.

Comment: Wasn't sure if mongoose is using a cursor behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes, so it's better to stream the query result in cases like this.  See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17689027/1259510